# Process finished with exit code 1 in debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I use Pycharm 2017.1 and (which I updated lately, but this problem occurred before) and the following code in file main_test:

```
print('test')
```

When I run the code it shows the following text:

> D:\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/Tom/PycharmProjects/crawl/test/main_test.py
>   test
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

In debug mode, it worked fine, but now when I use debug mode I get the following message:

> D:\Python35-32\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 53523 --file C:/Users/Tom/PycharmProjects/crawl/test/main_test.py
>   pydev debugger: process 19104 is connecting
>
> Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.3780.115)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I've tried to update to the newest version, to invalidate caches and restarted, but nothing of these seems to work. Did you encounter such a problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I knew that if I ask a question I will resolve the problem.

What I did (after creating a backup).
I deleted the directory '.idea' in my project and restarted Pycharm.
Now, the debugger works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into similar issue and solved by re-enabling breakpoints, here are my steps:

1. Open "View Breakpoints" (two big red circles next to two little
   circles on the debug panel; or ctrl+shft+F8)
2. Disable all breakpoints
3. Re-enable the breakpoint in your current code
4. Run the debug again